# How to install pyspark-cassandra

Tags: python, apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, sbt

I want to install pyspark-cassandra so that i can run spark query to cassandra database in jupyter notebook.

https://github.com/anguenot/pyspark-cassandra

Above is the git page for it. I tried to download the git directory and do sbt compile. But still not able to do "import pyspark_cassandra" in my notebook

Anyone has experience on successfully install it?
Or any better way to run spark jobs to cassandra database in jupyter notebook?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it as a jar file on clicking the files column here : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/anguenot/pyspark-cassandra/2.4.0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33624356)